# How to protect Sqlite3 database with password that using in desktop application

Tags: sqlite, python

I am creating database with `Qtsql.QSqlDatabase` using with in `python`. I want to protect my Database with password. I am using this database for my desktop applications. If it is possible, How to do this. or is there any or other databases way to create database with password protected.

```
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")#database
db.setDatabaseName("project.db")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlite doesn't come with encryption built in, however you can enable encryption in sqlite by either purchasing the official paid extension [here](https://www.sqlite.org/prosupport.html) for $2000. Or you can take a chance on one of the free alternative like this [one](https://github.com/resilar/sqleet#uri-configuration-interface). I have no idea how well the free versions will work, but I imagine the paid one is quite robust and up to date.

You will also need to build a custom qt sql driver by following the instructions [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qsqlite). And finally you must run this sql immediately after opening the database

```
PRAGMA key='your-secret-key';
```